# Is it possible to view git diffs using a GUI side-by-side tool on Mac?

Tags: macos, git, diff

I really hate visualizing diffs using the default UNIX `diff` tool.  Is it possible to do view git diffs using a GUI tool that will nicely display the local and remote side-by-side, similar how it is possible to set the `mergetool` to be `DiffMerge` and when you do

```
git mergetool myfile.txt
```

it pops the DiffMerge GUI for easier visualization and merging?  I am using OSX.

Comment: For the Windows users coming here via Google: You can use kdiff3 as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33308482/873282

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You could use `opendiff`. It is a command line tool which opens the GUI of [FileMerge](https://www.google.com/search?q=filemerge).

You could instruct Git to use it automatically for `git-mergetool` with:

```
git config --global merge.tool opendiff
```

If you want it for `git-difftool` as well:

```
git config --global diff.tool opendiff
```

And you could also disable the prompting for every file with:

```
git config --global difftool.prompt false
```

---

For more details type: `git help config` and search with `/` for the different options.

---

P.S. If you don't have `opendiff` installed you could install it together with the Developer Tools from Xcode: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/opendiff.1.html

**UPDATE**: In recent versions of Xcode, FileMerge is now bundled with Xcode. You cannot install FileMerge as a standalone program. `opendiff` is still in its command-line utilities which are standalone.

Comment: I followed what you suggested but when I type `git diff myfile.txt` nothing happens and I have no idea why. opendiff is working properly. Any ideas on what I can try?

Comment: FileMerge doesn't seem to like non-ASCII files.

Comment: @Flimm I've found this old article addressing the non-ASCII problem with FileMerge http://jasonfharris.com/blog/2010/07/filemerge-and-utf-8/ I hope it helps.

Comment: I ran `git config --global diff.tool opendiff` but still getting diff output in plain text on command line GUI

Comment: @ParthTamane, maybe you used "git diff ..." instead of "git difftool ..." to see the differences?  I think you'll need to use "git difftool ..." to see the differences using opendiff.

Comment: @Dracula this might happen if you are doing a merge, in which case you need `git config --global merge.tool opendiff` and then run `git mergetool`

Answer (score 3):

P4Merge from Perforce is pretty good and the standalone P4Merge application is free. You can get it at http://www.perforce.com/product/components/perforce-visual-merge-and-diff-tools

Also, if you are using SublimeText than http://www.sublimerge.com/ is also a good tool.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you aren't using Python, having PyCharm installed is worth it for its great Git integration. It's a good general-purpose editor and has a good visual diff+merge tool. The merge tool includes a triple-pane interface with intuitive code block selection. The community edition is free and works on my installation of MacOS High Sierra.

Answer (score 1):

I use BBEdit for this purpose. I think its diff display works very well. I have it set as my git external diff tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Visual Studio Code on your Mac, then you can install the [Diff Folder](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=L13RARY.l13-diff) extension to compare files and folders of checked out code.

Its very configurable - can exclude files based on regexp, open file diff to the side etc.

Its also easy to use !

Answer (score -4):

If you have the two different files, WinMerge does a very nice side-by-side comparison. I don't know if it's available for non-Windows platforms. Also, some systems will let you choose your own comparison tool, while others are hard coded to something specific -- I don't know about your Git environment.

Comment: It's not available on Mac.