# How can I configure KDiff3 in Git Extensions?

Tags: git, git-extensions, kdiff3

When I open [Git Extensions](https://gitextensions.github.io/), the result is like this:

[image]

I try to repair it. I click the repair button. But there isn't any action.

I get some reference: *[Git: How can I configure KDiff3 as a merge tool and diff tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308482/git-how-configure-kdiff3-as-merge-tool-and-diff-tool)*.

I try it like this:

[image]

But it does not work.

How can I solve this problem?

#### Environment

- OS: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
- Git 2.49

Comment: are you getting any error

Comment: @RJ, No. There is no error. Like the image above

Comment: for me looks like the link you have shared has everything you need. Have you checked your path variables mentioned in that previous question. have you got 64 bit version of KDiff extension ?

Comment: @RJ, No. I don't have KDiff3 folder

Comment: can you just make sure you have installed the correct version of Kdiff and added to your path variables?

Comment: @RJ, Seems I have not install KDiff3. Do I need to reinstall git extensions? Or there can only install KDiff3?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156725/discussion-between-rj-and-success-man).

Answer (score 12):

Check if KDiff3 is installed and in which folder (to verify the path).

I was also getting the same problem and had run the mentioned Git commands, but it didn't help.
Later I realized that my KDiff3 is installed under "Program Files (x86)" folder, not "Program Files".

I have changed the folder name in Git commands, for example:

Instead of

```
git config --global --add mergetool.kdiff3.path "C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe"
```

I used the below and executed it again:

```
git config --global --add mergetool.kdiff3.path "C:/Program Files (x86)/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe"
```

And it solved the problem.

Comment: so strange, i needed the exact reverse. I ended up reinstalling KDiff3 and manually changed the install path to "Program Files (x86)", once finished I hit repair in gitextensions and it worked this time.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you have downloaded the light version of the installer which doesn't include KDiff3.

Please download and install the complete installer from *https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/releases/latest*.

You can also just download and install KDiff3 yourself. We bundle and ship the version 0.9.97, which you can download from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/kdiff3/files/kdiff3/0.9.97/

Besides, you can install any other diffmerge tool too and configure Git Extensions to use that. For instance, I don't like KDiff3 and use [Perforce's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perforce) [P4Merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools#General) instead.

BTW, your version is outdated. The current version is 2.50.02 (as of November 2017).

Comment: As of version 2.51.02, `Git` and `Kdiff` are not included in the installer. You should install them manually.

Comment: Yes, though 2.51.02 was release in May '18, and the question was posted well before it.

Comment: My comment was just a notification for future viewers of the question/answer :)