# How do I install tkdiff on windows?

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

I set up Git today to work with GitHub. I want to use tkdiff as my default diff tool. I remember I used it before and it was nice and easy.

I downloaded the zip file from their website and see a tkdif file in the zip. However, I am not sure how to install it. Where do I place the file?

Additionally, what is the correct way to set tkdiff as the default diff/merge tool?

Thank you!

Comment: Is that me or it's not a windows tool? Do you confuse with kdiff3?

Comment: yea i couldn't figure out how to get it to work on windows. went with kdiff3 instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the folder which contains `tkdiff.exe` to your `%PATH%` (where you have uncompressed [tkdiff 4.3.5](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tkdiff/files/tkdiff/4.3.5/)).
2. Configure the tool in Git:

   ```
   git config --global diff.tool tkdiff
   git config --global difftool.tkdiff.cmd "\"C:\\Path\\to\\tkdiff.exe\" -s \"\$LOCAL\" -d \"\$REMOTE\""
   ```

Note that [tkdiff wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tkdiff) does not mention any *recent* Windows support (using TclTk)

So you might want to [consider instead `kdiff3`](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/), as commented, which does actually has a `kdiff3.exe`.

See "[Git: How configure KDiff3 as merge tool and diff tool](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33308482/6309)"

Comment: I used KDiff3 per your link and it worked. the only thing I had to add was 

$ git config --global diff.tool kdiff3

Also, is there a way to default to KDiff3 when typing 'git diff'?

Comment: @trustory Not with `git diff` directly, but just typing `git difftool` will launch the tool you have previously configured (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26732990/6309)