# git diff does not open opendiff on Mac

Tags: git, macos, git-diff, opendiff

I'm using git to work on a text document concurrently, and I'm trying to find a nice visual way to see the changes that were done by others. I can do this by typing `git diff` but the result is on the Terminal. I was reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486481/is-it-possible-to-view-git-diffs-using-a-gui-side-by-side-tool-on-mac) where it seems it's possible to configure git to use `opendiff` as the default viewer for diff. Yet, when I type the commands

```
$ git config --global merge.tool opendiff
$ git config --global diff.tool opendiff
$ git config --global difftool.prompt false
```

and I do `git diff` I still get the output on the Terminal. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the commands `git difftool` (instead of `git diff`) and `git mergetool` (instead of `git merge`) for git to use opendiff.